# How to send Collection of abstract types with ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-core, serialization, jsonserializer, derived-types

I am trying to send back a collection of `abstract` types in a `Controller` using `ActionResult`.I do not know how to tell the serializer to also include derived type(s) specific properties:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
}
public class D1:Base
{
    public string D1Value{get;set;}
}
public class D2:Base
{
    public bool IsD2Value{get;set;}
}

public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Base>>> GetAll()
{
   var collection=new []{ new D1 {  Id=1, D1Value="hi"} ,new D2 {Id=2, IsD2Value=true}};
   return StatusCode(200,collection);
}
```

How can i reach this result in a easy and elegant way.I have checked the `JsonSerializer` options but in my case i am not the one that is doing the serialization.

**What i get**

```
[{ "Id":1} ,  { "Id":2 }]
```

**What i want**

```
[{ "Id":1,"D1Value":"hi" } ,  { "Id":2 , "IsD2Value":true }]
```

Comment: Could you please edit your results, because both of them are same.

Comment: It was a typo , my bad.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian, you can put `D1` and `D2` into `List<object>`, then return them directly, I have updated my answer, hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Base>>> GetAll()
        {
             var collection = new List<object>() 
             { 
                 new D1 { Id = 1, D1Value = "hi" }, 
                 new D2 { Id = 2, IsD2Value = true } 
             };
            return StatusCode(200, collection);
        }
```

Here is the test result:
[image]

Comment: `"I have checked the JsonSerializer options but in my case i am not the one that is doing the serialization."`

Comment: @RafiHenig, ok , just to remove  JsonConvert.SerializeObject ,and return `List<object>` directly, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use new ArrayList() instead of List.